# Errors while using ABC_mcmc function:

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I am trying to use the ABC_mcmc function over 4 random values given in the ParPrior. I get the error:

> Error in if (dist_simul < dist_max) { :
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
   X<-1:45
   Y <- c(35326L, 30339L, 23379L, 21877L, 18629L, 17627L, 15691L, 15435L, 
   14205L, 11732L, 10560L, 10592L, 9939L, 7491L, 4928L, 3427L, 8123L, 
   9027L, 8733L, 9599L, 8737L, 9135L, 8548L, 7279L, 8940L, 8459L, 
   8460L, 7700L, 6817L, 7167L, 7089L, 7091L, 7538L, 9206L, 9680L, 
   5876L, 7799L, 8384L, 10586L, 8623L, 7848L, 5534L, 6610L, 6539L, 
   6650L)

n<-length(X)
observedData<-rnorm(n,0,0.01)
g=10000
ParPrior=list(c("unif",0.01,100000),c("unif",0.001,10),
c("unif",0.0001,1),c("unif",0.001,2))
sim.abc <- function(par){ 
c(Y-(par[1]*exp((-par[3]*X)+((par[2]*X^par[4])/par[4]))))
}

model.abc<-ABC_mcmc(method="Marjoram", model=sim.abc, prior=ParPrior, 
summary_stat_target=observedData,tolerance_quantile=0.001, n_rec=g)**
```

Please help

Comment: The variables `X,Y` are undefined. Could you please edit your question to include definitions for them (fake is fine)? Otherwise, others cannot run your code.

Comment: Sure, here you go!